# What's the meaning of 年前 in the context of "年前估计出不来"?

Tags: translation, meaning-in-context

I asked a factory about how long to produce.

> 生产多久？

They replied:

> 年前估计出不来

Translation tools shows: "Years ago".
Does it mean that they haven't been able to produce it for several years, or because it's near Chinese New Year, they won't be able to produce it before the new year?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

年前 means "before the new year(lunar)". 年 is lunar new year, and 前 is before.

估计 represents a approximate tone, like "most likely"

出不来 means cannot finish the production.

So the whole sentence means "Most likely we cannot finish the production before the lunar new year."

Comment: My answer treats 估计 as a noun (estimation) and your answer treats 估计 as a verb (guess). Not sure which one the factor staff meant to say. In either case, the production could not be finished before next year

Comment: @TangHo to my understanding, if the sentence means 'they can't give you an estimation', it will be 年前估计不出来

Comment: Yes, to my understanding, it should be 質素， not 素質， it should be 警員， not 員警， I presume it is possible that Mainland Chinese would say it that way

Comment: I reckon both answers are plausible since the answer is ambiguous. If it were "年前估计生產不来" would be much better.

Answer (score 1):

年前估计出不来 sounds like they can't give you an estimation because it is near the new year. After the new year when everyone is back to work and all the suppliers re-opened, they can then estimate how long it takes to finish the production